# WinAPI, изменение пункта меню

Tags: c, winapi

Создал диалоговое окно через ресурсы. Добавил меню(верхнее). Добавил меню к диалоговому окну через настройки студии. Запустил - меню на месте.
Добавил обработчик нажатия на кнопку меню:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    switch (LOWORD(wp))
    {
    case ID_MAINMENU:
    {
        static bool isMainThread(true);

        if (isMainThread)
            ModifyMenu(hMenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING | MF_CHECKED , GetMenuItemID(hMenu, 0), "текс1");
        else
            ModifyMenu(hMenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING | MF_UNCHECKED , GetMenuItemID(hMenu, 0), "текс2");

        isMainThread = isMainThread == true ? false : true;
        break;
    }

    default:
        break;
    }
```

Чего пытаюсь добиться: чтобы по нажатию текст менялся и пункт получал отметку\снимал её. Что выходит: галочку так и не увидел, текст обновляется только при обновлении окна. Само оно не обновляется, так что надо навести мышь, перетащить за границу дисплея. Пробовал `InvalidateRect`, `UpdateWindow` и функцию `SetMenuItemInfo` - не помогло.

P.S.: IDE Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому-нибудь пригодится.

1. Для строки меню нельзя активизировать состояние `MF_CHECKED`, [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-checkmenuitem) написано в дополнении подробнее.
2. Для перерисовки меню следует использовать функцию `DrawMenuBar(HWND hwnd)`